# Lazy logging with multiline strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

When logging it is recommended to use lazy strings, meaning the string formatting will only get evaluated if the logging string will get put out. E.g. a message with logging level `debug` won't get evaluated when the logging level is set to `information` or higher.

However I can't figure out out to use long multiline strings with lazy formatting.

```py
# This is not lazy
# Also it is ugly because you need to put the extra spaces at the end of each string
logging.info(("Some string %s that " +
              "is %d characters " +
              "long."), 
              str_name, str_len)
```

```py
# This is lazy but the formatting is awful because the white space gets printed, too
logging.info("""Some string %s that
                is %d characters
                long.""",
             str_name, str_len)

# results in:
# Some string MyString that
#                 is 123 characters
#                 long.
```

What other ways are there to produce nicely formatted strings that get formatted lazily? Note: I don't need any line breaks in my log messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution that I know is

```py
logging.info("Some string %s that "
             "is %d characters "
             "long.",
             str_name, str_len)
```

This will evaluate lazily and produce a single line logging message, however you still have to specify the extra space at the end of each line.